# Paypal integration with Google application engine-python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, paypal

I have to integrate paypal with my application which is built on app engine patch with python.

I searched over the web and found some issues reported in paypal integration with google application engine like here:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/9059b0750c45703b/b1d0611dd4b04273

There is a  paypalx-gae-toolkit

http://code.google.com/p/paypalx-gae-toolkit/ but this is for java.

Is there a similar toolkit for python?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a space before the URL definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have no problem accessing the paypal URL's FWIW...

The thread you are referencing is from 2008...

Comment: Yes, I have successfully integrated it with app engine, was afraid of those links actually. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The official toolkit for Python wasn't released yet, so a promising library seems to be 
[paypal-python](http://github.com/patcoll/paypal-python). It is actively developed at least. One problem is that it requires Python 2.6 or 2.7, but maybe it would not be hard to backport it to Python 2.5.

There are also [some projects on Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:paypal+python&projectsearch=Search+projects), but none seems very updated.

Answer (score 0):

[Paypal-python](https://github.com/duointeractive/paypal-python) works in 2.5.

Comment: Does it handle Paypal Instant Payer Notification (IPN) (https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an interesting post on IPN [here](http://learnbysoft.blogspot.com/2010/09/paypal-ipn-google-app-engine-python.html).  I haven't tried it.