# Using PayPal with AppEngine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, paypal-ipn, tipfy

I'm looking to use Google AppEngine (Python). The Tipfy framework looks very good. How do I add PayPal and/or Google Web Payments into my app.

Is there a simple extension or similar that I can drop in?

Comment: Please search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+paypal

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paypal integration with Google application engine-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634791/paypal-integration-with-google-application-engine-python)

Comment: Yes but I'm not using Django and the other thread you gave gives no answer so this question is stil valid IMHO

Comment: Did you check any of the other dozens of questions in the search results?  Please check those.  When you're done reading all the other related questions, please indicate how yours is actually different.  Your question is too short (and too vague) for anyone else to know how it's different from existing questions.  Please add details.  Please read existing questions.

Comment: For your info S Lott I did read the other questions. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Here's the blog entry where they introduce the PayPal X toolkit for GAE/J:

Wednesday, June 30, 2010
PayPal introduces PayPal X Platform Toolkit for Google App Engine
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/06/paypal-introduces-paypal-x-platform.html

In that article it says that they are working on the Python version.

If you have the flexibility you could wait for this official support, otherwise check one of the older stackoverflow topics on this issue where they discuss unofficial solutions.