# Sandbox server access denied in Java app (works fine with cURL)

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm attempting a simple Pay call using the Adaptive Payments API. I am receiving the following exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission svcs.sandbox.paypal.com resolve)
```

Here's a bit of my Java code to give you an idea of what I'm doing.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay");
httpPost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", USER_ID);
httpPost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD", PASSWORD);
httpPost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE", SIGNATURE);

httpPost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID", APPLICATION_ID);

httpPost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "JSON");
httpPost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "JSON");

/* Bunch of stuff to build my JSON and put it in an Entity */

httpPost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

This throws the exception. When I try the suggested cURL command though, it works fine:

```
curl -s --insecure -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: My_USERID" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: My_PASSWORD" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: My_SIGNATURE" -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay -d "{\"actionType\":\"PAY\", \"currencyCode\":\"USD\", \"receiverList\":{\"receiver\":[{\"amount\":\"1.00\",\"email\":\"rec1_1312486368_biz@gmail.com\"}]}, \"returnUrl\":\"http://www.example.com/success.html\", \"cancelUrl\":\"http://www.example.com/failure.html\", \"requestEnvelope\":{\"errorLanguage\":\"en_US\", \"detailLevel\":\"ReturnAll\"}}"

{"responseEnvelope":{"timestamp":"2013-08-07T13:00:11.846-07:00","ack":"Success","correlationId":"0f33d4304a29b","build":"6941298"},"payKey":"AP-5GA81571BX790024K","paymentExecStatus":"CREATED"}
```

Any ideas as to why I'm receiving this exception?

Comment: Are you doing this on Google App Engine or another Google platform? GAE has had some odd blocking of PayPal some time go.

Comment: Yes, I am doing it on GAE. Any references or other Stack issues about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#The_Sandbox

GAE applications can't communicate directly with other hosts. They have to use GAE's URL fetch service, as opposed to Apache HttpClient as I was doing.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/

Using the above link, I was able to set up a connection and get a response from the PayPal sandbox server. Here is my final code if it's helpful to anyone:

```
URL url = new URL(PAY_ENDPOINT);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setRequestProperty("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", USER_ID);
connection.setRequestProperty("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD", PASSWORD);
connection.setRequestProperty("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE", SIGNATURE);

connection.setRequestProperty("X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID", APPLICATION_ID);

connection.setRequestProperty("X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "JSON");
connection.setRequestProperty("X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "JSON");

/* Form JSON into "requestStr" */

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.write(requestStr);
writer.close();

// Read response into StringBuffer
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    stringBuffer.append(line);
}
reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Google [has](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/kFmwdQxFcDs) [controversially](http://techcrunch.com/2008/06/10/google-app-engine-accidentally-blocks-paypal/) [blocked](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/coincidence-or-not-google-app-engine-blocks-paypal/7087/) PayPal. A new system called [PaypalX](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/06/paypal-introduces-paypal-x-platform.html) acts as a paypal API, and has been released 2 years after the block. You can read up more on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758827/using-paypal-with-appengine-python) and its links. Namely, it requires less URL manipulation, instead using higher-level actions regarding a transaction.